# Swift 3 Transition Error

Tags: swift3, transition, cube

I am using transition function to have **cube effect** with function as shown and getting error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 nan; 667 343]'

The above error occurs when popped among **view controllers** (**UiNavigationcontroller with 5 view controllers in shared instance**) after orientation is changed.

I am not able to fix it ,please help

```
 func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {


    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toView = toViewController.view
    let fromView = fromViewController.view

    let direction: CGFloat = reverse ? -1 : 1
    let const: CGFloat = -0.005

    toView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint()
    toView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:direction == 1 ? 0 : 1,y: 0.5)
    fromView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:direction == 1 ? 1 : 0,y: 0.5)

    var viewFromTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(direction * CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    var viewToTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-direction * CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    viewFromTransform.m34 = const
    viewToTransform.m34 = const

    containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: direction * containerView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0)
    toView?.layer.transform = viewToTransform

    print("container view frame: \(containerView.frame) subviews container \(containerView.subviews)")

    containerView.addSubview(toView!)
    // App crashes here giving error

    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
        containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -direction * containerView.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0)
        fromView?.layer.transform = viewFromTransform
        toView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }, completion: {
        finished in
        containerView.transform = .identity
        fromView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        toView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        fromView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        toView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)

        if (transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled) {
            toView?.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    })        
}
```